# Javascript array of objects: Best way to return a value?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects in Javascript with two keys with this structure:

```
"data": [
  {
  "description": "Unknown",
  "type": 0
  },
  {
  "description": "On",
  "type": 1
  },
  {
  "description": "Off",
  "type": 2
  },
  ...
  ]
```

I want to pass it a 'type' numeric value and if it finds it in the array, returns me the description value. For example, if I pass '0', I want it to return 'Unknown'.

This is easily done with a for or forEach loop, but there is an inbuilt function in JS that lets me do it in a single line?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: If you're doing this often, you'll want to flip the data structure to turn it into `{0: 'Unknown', ...}` for fast lookup.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use either `find`

```js
var data = [{ description: "Unknown", type: 0 }, { description: "On", type: 1 }, { description: "Off", type: 2 }];
  
console.log(data.find(({ type }) => type === 1).description);
```

or for faster access use a hash table for the types

```js
var data = [{ description: "Unknown", type: 0 }, { description: "On", type: 1 }, { description: "Off", type: 2 }], 
    types = Object.assign(...data.map(({ type, description }) => ({ [type]: description })));
  
console.log(types[1]);
```

or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var data = [{ description: "Unknown", type: 0 }, { description: "On", type: 1 }, { description: "Off", type: 2 }], 
    types = data.reduce((m, { type, description }) => m.set(type, description), new Map);
  
console.log(types.get(1));
```

Comment: @Liam If you have ES6, you can use `map` function.

Answer (score 0):

In one liner you can [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the list.

```js
var obj=[{
  "description": "Unknown",
  "type": 0
  },
  {
  "description": "On",
  "type": 1
  },
  {
  "description": "Off",
  "type": 2
  }];
  var filterType=1;
  console.log(obj.filter(e=>e.type == filterType)[0]['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the attached code snippet , which gives the desired output.

- Find function to itreat throughout your array to match the condition i.e in this case the passedIndex to check whether it is present in list
- If present return the item

```js
var list = [{
    "description": "Unknown",
    "type": 0
  },
  {
    "description": "On",
    "type": 1
  },
  {
    "description": "Off",
    "type": 2
  }
];

function findItem(index) {
  var result = list.find(function(item) {
    if (item.type == index) {
      return item;
    }
  });
  return result.description;
}
var description = findItem(2);
console.log('The Description is "' + description + '"')
```

.